# how to move from poid to hilo in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have been having a lot of trouble with deadlocks.  I've received some really useful [feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353108/how-to-replicate-and-retry-deadlocks-in-nhibernate) that suggested this may be a side effect of my use of [identity](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/12/21/identity-the-never-ending-story.aspx) which is a regular id. My application is of reasonable size. 20-30 entities. Making a major change like this is quite a scary proposition. So would be very grateful for some feedback

1) what would i need to do to change to hilo. This application has quite a lot of data. Would i need to do some kind of data migration.

2) is hilo the correct choice, would guid be an easier upgrade.

An example entity mapping. I'm using nhibernate 2

```
<class name="Post" table="Post">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32" column="Id" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Company" column="CompanyId"   class="EStore.Domain.Model.Company, EStore.Domain" />
    <many-to-one name="Retailer" column="RetailerId"   class="EStore.Domain.Model.Retailer, EStore.Domain" />
    <many-to-one name="Parent" column="ParentId"   class="EStore.Domain.Model.Post, EStore.Domain" />
    <many-to-one name="PostStatus" column="PostStatusId"   class="EStore.Domain.Model.PostStatus, EStore.Domain" />
  </class>
```

Answer (score 0):

highlow needs a source for high (table or sequence) and calculates a lowvalue.
you need a sequence/table which value * maxlowvalue(the value you define in the mapping) is greater than the highest id in your database/table(if you give each table a different highvalue sequence/table)